# Client is IPv4 and Server is IPv6 getting java.net.ConnectionException

Tags: ipv6

I have Hadoop Service listening on **25000** port with IPv6 IP. Say 2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888:**25000**

But when client sends request to IPv4 IP say 10.20.200.10:**25000** getting java.net.ConnectionException

Without changing the server side code, how can we handle this scenario?

Comment: By making the client IPv6 capable? IPv4 and IPv6 just aren't compatible.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. With Ipv6 client it's working fine. Only problem with Ipv4 client.

Comment: An TCP/IP endpoint are actually identified by *four* (or three, depending on protocol) things: The address and the port (for protocols supporting ports, like TCP and UDP), as commonly taught, but also the protocol and protocol *version*. A TCPv4 client can't connect to a TCPv6 server.

Comment: Just a thought.. Is this can be achieved using IP forwarding or DNS or DSlite lpv6?